# Can we do RPC connection to corda using NodeJs?

Tags: rpc, corda

I know CordaRPCClient is there to do the RPC connection to the network.
Is there any possibility, can we do that happen in NodeJS so that I can write my middle ware in nodejs.

Is there something corda team is planning to build for client library for NodeJS implementation of RPCops.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this Corda sample](https://github.com/nitesh7sid/cordapp-example-nodejs-server-graalvm)

The example demonstrates a node.js server which uses corda rpc-3.1 library running in GraalVM.

Also, take a look at [Braid](https://gitlab.com/bluebank/braid). Braid is a reactive rpc library for exposing your services and consuming them in Javascript